# After Upgrade to Android Studio 4.2, unable to debug my code

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.2

The previous version debugger working fine but upgraded to android studio 4.2 version unable to debug the code.

> Error with like Debugger process finished with exit code 127.

I tried with invalidating caches/restart the android studio. Still not able to resolved the issue.

Comment: try remove .gradle, .idea  folders and restart android studio

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu `sudo apt install libncurses5`

Issue resolved